# Why output differs between R and SPSS when run Poisson glm on count data

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, spss, poisson-regression

I am puzzled why output differs between R and SPSS when run Poisson glm on count data? While R returns Estimate, Standard Error, z value and Pr(>|z|), SPSS does Walt χ2, df and significance.

Answer (score 0):

If you take the square root of the $\chi^2$ values from SPSS they should be identical to the values of $Z$ from R, providing the SPSS $\chi^2$ is based on 1 d.f.   Also, the Pr(>|z|) from R is the same as the significance for SPSS.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick comment. This is very helpful. Can I report just χ2 values and significant codes from SPSS for a research paper?

Comment: I found that the square root of the χ2 values from SPSS is similar but not exactly the same as that of R. I might set something wrong for SPSS although I follow the instruction of IBM...

Comment: I was first going to mention that you need to obtain the same regression coefficients from each package first, and then sqrt(chi2) will be exactly equal to z.  The chi2 distribution for each regression coefficient has 1 degree of freedom (d.f.=1), which is the only case where sqrt(chi2)=z.   Above 1.d.f. for the chi2 distribution, this relationship does not hold.  Make sure you are not looking at the goodness-of-fit chi2, since the degrees of freedom are equal to the number of records minus the number of regression coefficients.   (GOF statistics might also report deviance and Pearson chi2).

Comment: I see. I will look at the regression coefficients. Thank you!